# How to make sense of USB connectors?

Tags: usb, connector, cables, interconnect

It seems USB connectors have 4 dimensions:

1. Type A, B, or C.  And sometimes type AB.
2. Full, mini, or micro.
3. Male or female.
4. USB version.

Surprisingly, I can't find a good reference on those.  If, for example, I want to power my device via USB (power only, no data), I want a female jack: but mini or micro? Type A, B, or AB? How do I make sense of this?

Comment: Technically "mini" has been deprecated, and there is only one type-C (full/mini/micro only apply to A/B/AB).

Comment: Also with USB-C (both devices and cables) you have lots of variants in terms of supported features, power, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all designed to solve certain scenarios.

USB was designed to connects hosts to devices.

The classic USB use case is plugging a mouse into a computer. The mouse has a USB plug; the computer has a USB socket. You put the plug in the socket. That's type A. It's the classic USB connector you know and love. If your device is meant to plug into a computer or charger that has a type A socket, then it's a good option to put a type A plug on your device. The voltage is always 5 volts. The maximum current is, I think, 2.1 amps from most chargers.

Some devices are really big and heavy, like printers. They didn't want to make printers with permanently attached USB cables - imagine throwing out your printer because you broke the cable - so they made a cable that would be plugged in at both ends, and the printer end became type B. You plug the A end of the cable into the computer, and the B end (the square-ish one) into the printer. So far, so good.

Along came the mobile phone revolution and USB B ports, those big sturdy square ones designed for printers, are really way too big to fit inside cellphones. So they made a small version, which was mini-B, and when phones got even smaller, that was still too big, so they made a micro-B. Cheap phones and many power banks today still use micro-B. If you want the same cables that fit into cheap phones and power banks to fit into your device, use a micro-B socket. If you're undecided, your device is quite small, you don't want it to have a permanently attached cable, and you don't have a reason to use type C, then micro-B is a good choice.

You can forget about micro-A and micro-AB. I think some phones did use micro-AB, but it's compatible with micro-B plugs which is what most people will put in them. The micro-A plug only becomes relevant if you want to use one of these phones as a host, e.g. to plug a mouse into it. And then you still wouldn't have a micro-A plug on a mouse - you'd have a normal A plug, and plug it into an adapter that goes with the phone. micro-A is only relevant if you're making one of these adapters.

You can forget about anything mini, unless you're making an accessory for a graphing calculator. Remember that mini was designed to fit in cellphones but it was still too big for cellphones, so hardly anything uses it. Even the USB consortium recommends that you don't use it.

Then there's type C. I literally have no idea why type C was invented except to make everything more confusing - I suspect it was because people wanted to plug their phones into their projectors. And then Apple went and made a laptop with *only* type C ports and now we're deep in this mess. If your device is meant to be plugged into a phone or an average laptop, that only has type C ports, then you'll have to use type C. It's also the only type that supports USB Power Delivery - if you want to get more power than standard USB charging power, you'll need USB-PD and that requires a type C cable. If a good quality cable is used, USB-PD can move stupid amounts of power, enough to charge laptops.

There's also Quick Charge, a proprietary Qualcomm protocol that doesn't require type C - not sure if micro-B is allowed, but it works with type A and B ports. USB-PD seems to be a lot more popular because it's a USB standard.

Comment: I believe Oneplus also has a fast charge protocol, distinct from QuickCharge or Power Delivery.

Answer (score 5):

You are making a device side which requires power, you are not making a host side.

So you can't use host side Type-A connectors. And since your device is not a dual role device you don't need AB either.

You need Type B if you want Micro or Mini. It will be unclear why you would want Mini as Micro has been long used already and now Type-C starts to be more common, but you are free to use any connector if you have matching plugs and cables.

You can read Wikipedia article on USB for detailed info.

Comment: Thanks.  Does that mean: Type A is host, Type B is device? The [part is designated](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/USB-Connectors_MOLEX-475900001_C136001.html) "Micro-AB Female".  What would that mean?

Comment: As in my answer, AB means dual role device and your gadget is not both a host and a device so you don't need to use it.

Comment: There are [power only USB-C connectors](https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/an-introduction-to-power-only-usb-type-c-connectors) available for this exact application.

Comment: @SRobertJames Those are probably micro-B connectors. A connectors are for host only, B connectors are for devices only. This avoids users connecting things together in invalid configurations (let's ignore the fact that currently you can buy type-A to type-A cables from China). However when phones became more powerful they started being able to be configured as host to connect to external devices (keyboards etc.) even thought their connectors are type-B meant for devices only. This configuration is call on-the-go or OTG and since you wouldn't want to desolder the connector on your phone...

Comment: ... the micro-B connectors on a lot of Android phones officially became both host and device connector

Comment: @slebetman you can also connect A-to-C adapter <-> C-to-C standard cable <-> A-to-C adapter and make that illegal cable as a chain of standard parts *facepalm*

Comment: @user253751 Not true, because, quote from standard, "USB Type-C receptacle to USB legacy adapters are explicitly not defined or allowed", so you would be constructing an illegal cable out or illegal parts.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to power my device via USB (power only, no data)

This simplifies design decision by quite a lot.

On the host side you have basically only 3 options that are widely in use:

- Type A (most regular PCs and the majority of wall chargers)
- micro B (phones with OTG capability)
- Type C (Macs and some wall chargers)

Of the 3 the rarest is charging from OTG hosts. If you really need to be able to charge your device from specific Android phones you may choose this otherwise you shouldn't use it.

So that generally narrows it down to USB A and USB C.

On the device side you generally have 3 choices:

- Type B
- micro B
- Type C

Of the 3 Type B is quite rare these days - typically only used by printers and 3D printers. This is because Type B connector is quite large. As a consequence Type B cables are less common than micro B or Type C cables. Typically you can only buy Type B cables from computer stores while micro B and Type C cables can easily be found at phone shops.

Note that if you want to follow the spec Type C charging is a little more complex than Type B charging.

So overall your choice is between 2:

- Type A to micro B: This is the most popular for niche devices.
- Type C to Type C: This is the more modern choice though to fully benefit form this you should use a USB-C charging chipset like the MAX14748 or equivalent.

It is tempting to use a Type C connector without following the USB C spec but don't. The RaspberryPi 4 did exactly that and found itself incompatible with the majority of chargers on the market. You need a charger specifically designed for the RaspberryPi 4 to run RaspberryPi 4 properly without risk of intermittent reboots when it's connected to a lot of devices.

Note that if your device is something large like a desktop scanner or a CNC cutter you really should use a Type B connector which makes the choice really simple:

- The clasic Type A to Type B: use for large machinery.

Comment: Alternatively, for C to C there is of course also the Type A to Type C, which is commonly used to connect Type C devices to (non-PD) wall chargers with Type A output.

Comment: Mini-B is still moderately common on cameras small specialist (e.g. label) printers, and other devices bigger than tablets but smaller than full size printers.  Maybe when these are completely redesigned they'll have micro-B or C, but while the designs are just being slightly updated, they're sticking to mini-B.  Mini-B has the advantage in some situations that it's far less likely to be "borrowed" by an annoying colleague wanting to charge their phone.

Comment: @ChrisH Which is exactly why you should avoid them when designing products. It's very difficult to get mini-B cables except from camera shops (which is even more rare than computer shops which themselves are not as common as phone shops). Basically they're not widely in use which disqualifies them form my widely in use list.

Comment: @slebetman as a designer of *non*-products I do tend to come at things from a different direction (and I read the question as being quite likely a similar case).  We're seriously considering mini-B for a few sets of in-house lab equipment where we need about 50mA at 5V right next to a PC. Full-size B would be so much easier to work with in this kit, but there's no room.

Comment: For some discussion of micro-B vs. type-C, see [this discussion about the KeyBrick One](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/180565-keybrick-one-rechargeable-battery-pack-for-powered-up/&page=2&tab=comments#comment-3304974). Main points: 1. USB type C connectors are considerably larger [than micro-B]  2. USB type C would require a good bit more circuitry (...) which comes at significant expense and with the matching board space requirement.

Comment: @ChrisH As a user of things I curse every time I get a PCB with mini-B. I have several PIC and AVR programmers with mini-B that I never use because I keep losing the cable. I ended up buying newer programmes with USB-C

Comment: @slebetman I have the opposite problem - too many mini-B cables from defunct devices.  In the design I'm looking at now, if we didn't use mini-B we'd make something like USB-A(male) to a DC coax jack, which seems pointless.  In this situation we can order cables from our reputable supplier of choice along with the connectors, or at home it would be eBay.